# Logistic regression - what is the example interpretation of standardized odds ratio?

Tags: regression, logistic, classification, modeling

Let's have an example:

The model is used to classify outcome (won, lost).

- variable_1 is having std_coefficient of 1.610 and std_odds_ratio of
  5.003
- variable_2 is having std_coefficeint of -2.675 and std_odds_ratio of

0.069 My interpretation is as follows:

- for every +SD change in variable_1 the likelihood of winning is equal
  to (5.003 - 1) * 100 = 400.3 % increase
- for every +SD change in variable_2 the likelihood of winning is equal
  to (1 - 0.069) * 100 = 93.1 % decrease

From my understanding as std_odds_ratio is calculated by exp(std_coefficient) it cannot be negative. How come one could have 400% increase but not 400% decrease in likelihood of outcome (won, lost)?

I there a symmetrical metric that would allow to have a consistent interpretation of <-infinity; +infinity> in likelihood % change?

This is the [reference](https://academic.oup.com/sf/article-abstract/89/4/1409/2235544).

Answer (score 1):

It would be a good idea to do a semi-deep dive into logistic regression before proceeding.  There are many textbooks and online resources.  Logistic regression is not a classifier but is a direct probability model.  Odds ratios do not provide relative likelihoods of an event.  Standardizing by standard deviations is not a good idea, and "standardized" odds ratios don't have a good interpretation.  Even more important, they have a hidden linearity assumption.  Percent change is not a good change measure because of asymmetry.

Comment: In my question there is a reference which seems to provide information that contradicts with Your response in my interpretation. I indeed would like to know more about logistic regression and I have studied it before the use in this example. I will look for more resources but the question still stands.

Comment: Your comment is not specific enough for me to know how to respond.